# Member of organization, how to join a board created by other member?

Tags: trello-organization, trello-boards

A member of my organization created a new Trello board.  I went to go join it, but I only see the option to subscribe, which does not add me to the board, such that I can join cards and such.  However, I can see the settings (greyed out) that state members of the organization can join the board without an invitation.

Am I missing a giant "join board" button or menu option in the UI somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to flag each new board (even if part of an organization) as open to your org (private by default) and then allow org members to join through settings.

[image: trello private default]

Answer (score 0):

Have the person who created the board make sure that under Board Settings that the 
"Allow Org Members to Join" is checked.  Any org member can join this board without being invited.

Then go into the Org page to view all boards and you should be able to join from there.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure there is a check mark next to the setting. Don't be confused by the text clearly saying "Any org member can join this board without being invited."

[image: unchecked]

[image: checked]